# Enumerate I-1 , I-2

Tags: lists, enumerate

I would like to enumerate a list using this: I-1 I-2 I-3 or TI-1 TI-2 TI-3, but a always get 1-1 or T1-1.

```
    \begin{enumerate}[I-1]
        \item dasfsd
        \item DSFASD
        \item ASDFAS
        \item AFSD
    \end{enumerate}
```

Help me please!!!!!!

Comment: You need to place the I or TI in braces since the I tells the enumerate package you should use capital Roman numerals; I.e., [{I}-1] and [{TI}-1].

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `enumitem` version (just for completeness), which does not need the `{I}` (but does need more information to set up the label) and is a little a bit more up-to-date and configurable (according to the author of `enumerate` ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={I-\arabic*}]
\item dasfsd
\item DSFASD
\item ASDFAS
\item AFSD
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add braces around the capital I, otherwise it is interpreted as a special character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{I}-1]
\item dasfsd
\item DSFASD
\item ASDFAS
\item AFSD
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```